# Reduce the file size of a PDF (except CLI)

Tags: pdf, ubuntu, file-converter

Currently, when I need to reduce the size of a PDF file  I use `ghostscript` in a CLI command like this (with some variances when I'm working with images):

```
$ gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=new.pdf old.pdf
```

This command works like a charm, but I'd like to know if exists any GUI tool for the same purpose that works on Ubuntu.

Some cool requirements (not mandatory):

- Select specific pages (with images, for example) to ignore in the reduce. The intention is to prevent a reduction in image resolution when this can make them unreadable;
- Specify a desired range for the file size;
- Free and Open Source is a plus;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ScanTailor](http://scantailor.org/), or [XnViewMP](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/) or both.

- free software
- cross-platform
- they can only work with TIFF images so you'll have to find a way to convert PDF to TIFF  (`gs` can do that too, but you're getting back to CLI) and then again merge TIFFs into PDF
- XnViewMP has better batch automation than ScanTailor

You can't specify a desired output size range, but if you apply compression and color settings correctly you'll get a relatively small size with good quality. I wrote about this on [my website](https://www.onetransistor.eu/2014/11/high-quality-scanning-and-low-file-size.html).